# Delete some elements from the array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to delete elements from the array `points`. This is how I do this. The problem is that `pts.length` is always the same, and the removed elements have the value `null`. Therefore at some moment I receive the error message `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    int ind = r.nextInt(pts.length);
    TSPPoint pt = points[ind];
    pts = removeElements(points,ind);
    solPoints[i] = pt;
    System.out.println(pts.length);
}

private static TSPPoint[] removeElements(TSPPoint[] input, int ind) {
    List<TSPPoint> result = new LinkedList<TSPPoint>();

    for(int i=0; i<input.length; i++)
        if(i != ind)
            result.add(input[i]);

    return (TSPPoint[]) result.toArray(input);
}
```

Comment: When you have weird results, use iterator.

Comment: Can you use `List<TSPPoint>` instead of `TSPPoint[]`? In particular, did you try `ArrayList`? Might make things easier for you.

Comment: @ᴍaroun ᴍaroun: how to use iterator for the array?

Comment: @tobias_k: no, because I had outofmemory issues.

Comment: I thought you were removing from a list..

Comment: you are going through `points` but changing `pts` ? and finally assigning it to `solPoints` ?

Comment: On closer inspection, it seems you want to create a permutation of the points. In this case you probably should do `pts = removeElements(pts,ind);`. Or better, use [Collections.shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)

Comment: @tobias_k: do you mean something like this?:  public static TSPSolution randomSolution(CostMatrix _cm, TSPPoint start, TSPPoint[] points) {
  List<TSPPoint> pts = new ArrayList<TSPPoint>(Arrays.asList(points));
  Collections.shuffle(pts);
  
  return new TSPSolution(start, (TSPPoint[]) pts.toArray());
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code seems to (be supposed to) do is to remove random elements from the original array of `points` and append them to the `pts` array, i.e., create a *permutation* of `points`.

If this is the case, I suggest converting your array to a `List` and using [`Collections.shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29).

Comment: do you mean something like this?: public static TSPSolution randomSolution(CostMatrix _cm, TSPPoint start, TSPPoint[] points) { List<TSPPoint> pts = new ArrayList<TSPPoint>(Arrays.asList(points)); Collections.shuffle(pts); return new TSPSolution(start, (TSPPoint[]) pts.toArray()); }

Comment: @KlausosKlausos Yes, something like that. Does it work?

Comment: At this line "return new TSPSolution(start, (TSPPoint[]) pts.toArray());" I receive the message "java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lits.aslogic.vrptw.TSPPoint;"

Comment: @KlausosKlausos It seems `toArray()` returns an `Object[]`. Have you tried [the generic version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T[]%29)?

Answer (score 1):

@nrathaus has found the bug for you. It's simply that you've got your arrays confused (you're passing `points` into `removeElements`, but using `pts` everywhere else).

But if memory churn is being an issue, there's a much more efficient way to implement `removeElements`, using [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) rather than a temporary `LinkedList`.:

```
private static TSPPoint[] removeElements(TSPPoint[] input, int ind) {
    TSPPoint[] rv;

    if (ind >= 0 && ind < input.length) {
        // New array will be one smaller
        rv = new TSPPoint[input.length - 1];
        if (rv.length > 0) {
            // Copy the bit before the element we delete
            if (ind > 0) {
                System.arraycopy(input, 0, rv, 0, ind);
            }

            // Copy the rest
            System.arraycopy(input, ind + 1, rv, ind, input.length - ind);
        }
    }
    else {
        // No change
        rv = input;
    }

    return rv;
}
```

Mind you, if you're doing this a lot, creating and releasing all of these arrays may not be ideal. Using a `List` throughout may be better.

Comment: Do you mean that I should use pts = removeElements(pts,ind); instead of pts = removeElements(points,ind);?

Comment: If I use pts = removeElements(points,ind);, I receive the error message java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
 at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)

Comment: @KlausosKlausos: *"Do you mean that I should use pts = removeElements(pts,ind);"* Presumably, given what the code seems to want to do. But again, all of these arrays are not likely to be the best way to do this...

Answer (score 1):

Wow, for deleting every element you recreate the rest of the array in a `LinkedList`, which you then turn into an array... The performance of this code, both in time and space, is terrible and so is readability, maintainability and testability.

Why not drop using arrays all together?.. convert `points` into an `ArrayList` and use `remove(index)` directly on that list and use an iterator of the llist to remove multiple elements as you iterate through?